# Having an endlessly scrollable table occupying the remaining space of the page

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I have several questions regarding organizing the CSS. I am using Semantic UI lib to power up my markup, but currently I am stuck on trying to make my table occupy the rest of the page, with no scroll on the main page, and only the table part scrollable. Is that possible?

The scroll should be begin from table body !

https://jsfiddle.net/nedgar8/azdbnhfq/1/

```
<body>
  <div class="ui fixed inverted menu">
    <a class="item" href="/">Main</a>
  </div>
  <div class="ui container">
      <table class="ui striped celled selectable table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>
              My header
            </td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="">My row 1 </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="">My row </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="">My row </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="">My row </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="">My row </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="">My row </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="">My row </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="">My row </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="">My row </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="">My row </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="">My row </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="">My row </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="">My row </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div> My Footer </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you want scroll only the table where main page will not scroll?

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow-x: scroll` in `ui-container` div. I set a hight here `300px`. After `300px` it will scroll vertically.

```
<body>
  <div class="ui fixed inverted menu">
    <a class="item" href="/">Main</a>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-container" style="height:300px;overflow-x: scroll;">
      <table class="ui striped celled selectable table">
       ................
      </table>
  </div>
  <div> My Footer </div>
</body>
```

I use some CSS in the `ui-container` to separate the header and footer.

```
body {
    padding: 1em;
}
.ui-container{
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-bottom:30px;
}
```